# Ошибка:NullPointerException at android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompatICS.setMenuVisibility

Tags: java, android

С чем связан не могу понять, сразу при старте выдается такая ошибка:

Разметка:
activity

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    tools:context="com.example.user.remainder.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/pager"/>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/background_light"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

main_activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    PreferanceHelper preferanceHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        PreferanceHelper.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext());
        preferanceHelper = PreferanceHelper.getInstance();//экземпляр
        runSplash();
        setUI();
    }

    public void runSplash() {
if(!preferanceHelper.getBoolean(PreferanceHelper.SPLASH_IS_INVISIBLE))
        {
            SplashFragment splashFragment = new SplashFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, splashFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        MenuItem splashItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_ssetings);
        splashItem.setChecked(preferanceHelper.getBoolean(PreferanceHelper.SPLASH_IS_INVISIBLE));
        return true;

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_ssetings) {
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            {
                preferanceHelper.putBoolean(PreferanceHelper.SPLASH_IS_INVISIBLE, item.isChecked());
            }

            return true;
        }
        return  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    //toolbar
    private void setUI(){
        Toolbar toolbar =(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if(toolbar !=null)
        {
            toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        TabLayout tablLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tablLayout.addTab(tablLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.current_task));
        tablLayout.addTab(tablLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.done_task));
        final ViewPager viewPager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(fragmentManager, 2);
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tablLayout));
        tablLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
код view.java
этот код я не писал,он авт. сгенерирован

```
 switch (flags & VISIBILITY_MASK) {
            case INVISIBLE:
                if (numFlags > 0) {
                    output += " ";
                }
                output += "INVISIBLE";
                // USELESS HERE numFlags++;
                break;
            case GONE:
                if (numFlags > 0) {
                    output += " ";//тут ругается
                }
                output += "GONE";
                // USELESS HERE numFlags++;
                break;
            default:
```

Gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.remainder"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.0'
}
```

Логи:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompatICS.setMenuVisibility(FragmentCompatICS.java:23)
                                                                              at android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat$ICSFragmentCompatImpl.setMenuVisibility(FragmentCompat.java:81)
                                                                              at android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat.setMenuVisibility(FragmentCompat.java:145)
                                                                              at android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:120)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:943)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1157)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: забыли код прикрепить, где происходит вылет

Comment: @Андроид Андроид
так раньше в логах синим это место подсвечивало,А сейчас нет,что прикреплять..

Comment: Учитывая характер ошибки, и то что приложение падает после запуска, проблема скорее всего в вашем стартовом активити. Выдайте немного его кода, если, конечно, он не секретен.

Comment: @Victor
добавил

Comment: @upward вы добавили фрагмент кода API андроида, а не код своего активити. попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: @Victor, в  шапке есть класс mainactivity